# Getting clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) when trying to install Java module for javascript

Tags: java, node.js, npm, electron

I need to install the Java module for an electron project that I am working on, but whenever I use

```
npm instal java
```

I get a long error that starts with

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

this is the full error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/nodejavabridge_bindings.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Maxwell/Documents/java-electron-test/node_modules/java
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN java-electron-test@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! java@0.12.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.12.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Maxwell/.npm/_logs/2020-05-19T20_35_43_345Z-debug.log
```

I am running MacOS Catalina Version 10.15.4